# How do I create a function parameter (variable) for the answers to an inquirer.prompt question in javascript? MySQL is also involved

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, parameters, inquirer

How do I create a function parameter (variable) for the answers to an inquirer.prompt question in JavaScript? I know how to do this without using variables, but to make my function addToTable easier to use throughout my code, I wanted to use parameters. A concatenation is being used for a MySQL query in the answer portion of my inquirer.prompt question. My problem is how do I pass data.department_name as a variable inside the concatenation.

```
function addToTable ( prompt_name , prompt_answer , table_name , table_col ){

    
    inquirer.prompt([
      {
        type: "input",
        name: prompt_name,
        message: "Type the " + prompt_name + " ?"
        
      }
    ]).then(function (data) {
  
      connection.query("INSERT " + table_name + " (" + table_col + ") VALUES ('" + prompt_answer + "')", function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
     
    })
  };

//then calling the function as so
addToTable("department_name" , "data.department_name" , "department", "name" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I searched for "Concatenate a dynamic variable name in Javascript" earlier. What worked for me was to put the parameter(prompt_name) in brackets. The function parameters looked as such:

```
function addToTable ( prompt_name , table_name , table_col )
```

nested inside that function with the second part of my inquirer.prompt looking like this:

```
connection.query("INSERT " + table_name + " (" + table_col + ") VALUES ('" + data[prompt_name] + "')"
```

and finally calling the function like this:

```
addToTable("department_name" , "department" , "name" );
```

therefore i got data.department_name to go where I wanted it at the correct time!